# Proof By Induction Divisibility Question: $12\mid 3^n + 7^{n-1} + 8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

Prove that $3^n + 7^{n-1} + 8$ is divisible by $12$ for all positive integers $n$.

I have proved it is true for $n=1$ and I have done the 'assume $n=k$' step, but after getting $3^{k+1} + 7^k + 8$, I am stuck. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 5):

HINT: $3^{k+1}+7^{k}+8=7(3^{k}+7^{k-1}+8)-4\cdot3^{k}-6\cdot8=7(3^{k}+7^{k-1}+8)-12(3^{k-1}+4)$

Clarification of where this comes from:
$3^{k+1}=3\cdot3^{k}=7\cdot3^{k}-4\cdot3^k$
similarly $8=7\cdot8-6\cdot8$

Comment: Much better than my expression. +1!

Comment: And since we assume that 3^k + 7^(k-1) +8, the first term is divisible by 12, and the second term is divisible by 12 due to its coefficient anyway, that answers the question. May I ask where the '4.3^k-6.8' comes from?

Comment: @Rich -- I have added a clarification of where these come from.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that $3^{k+1}+7^k+8 = 3\cdot\left(3^{k}+7^{k-1}+8\right)+4\cdot \left((3\cdot 2+1)^{k-1}-3-1\right)$ is divisible by $3$ and $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Your next step is to relate the expression you have for $k+1$ to the expression for $k$ (no need, incidentally, to change notation from $n$ to $k$)

Since the expression involves powers, you probably need to multiply by something, and $3$ and $7$ are the obvious candidates.

So let $f(k)=3^k+7^{k-1}+8$ then we have $$f(k+1)=3^{k+1}+7^k+8=3f(k)+g(k)$$ where $g(k)$ is to be found by putting in what we know for $f(k)$. We know that $12|f(k)$ and if we can prove that $12|g(k)$ we are done.

This knocks out the power of $3$, but doesn't immediately get you the whole way. But go confidently, one step at a time.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to split into the two cases: $\pmod 3$ and $\pmod 4$ then combine using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

I.e., we prove:

> $3^n+7^{n-1}+8 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ for all $n \geq 1$

and

> $3^n+7^{n-1}+8 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ for all $n \geq 1$.